# Remove "sub" host from URL with javascript // www.search.test.com - only want "test.com"

Tags: javascript, url, window, location, host

Got some different web applications:
- test.com
- search.test.com
- mysite.test.com
- awesome.test.com 
.. etc

I'm trying to make a global meny that always takes you back to the "test.com" site. Since we have different environments I cannot hard-code the url's in the menu. Is there a way to get only "test.com" using location or window in javascript.(or something else)

I only want the "main" host url.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085276/replace-subdomain-name-with-other-subdomain-using-javascript

Comment: Perfect ..  Ill delete my question